# facebook login doesnt work on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, facebook-graph-api

im tearing my hair out trying to solve this. my like page uses the exact code used on the facebook js sdk sample to see if the user likes the page. this works on all desktop browsers, but doesnt work on ipad. I just get a blank screen. i tried adding some text to the top of the page to check the page does get loaded and it does. the issue looks like its with fb.login?

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
            // This js didnt work, update the reload href further down !!! var currentUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mosquito-Digital/186527884694190?id=186527884694190&sk=app_629434517084781';
  var likesPage = false;
  var addisPageId = 'xxxxxxxxx'; //got this from http://graph.facebook.com/pagename


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//myurl.com/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {

            FB.api('/me/likes?fields=id', function(response) {

                for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
                    if(response.data[i].id == addisPageId) {
                        likesPage = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(likesPage) {
                    window.location = '/continuepage.aspx';
                    //document.getElementById("likePage").style.display = "inline";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("container_notlike").style.display = "inline";
                }
            });
        } else {
            window.parent.location = "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx";
            //document.getElementById("nologin").style.display = "inline";
        }
    }, {scope: 'user_likes'});
    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_gb/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <div id="container_notlike">
        <img src="/xxxxx/like-page-01.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="container_like">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if your Mobile Safari has "Block Pop-Ups" activated. If it's activated the FB.login won't work without any response/hint/error/whatever.

[Instruction](http://browsers.about.com/od/allaboutwebbrowsers/ss/iphonepopups.htm) how to deactivate Pop-Up Blocker on Mobile Safari.